# Replace Words proceeding it with Regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have two strings like this:

```
word=list()
word.append('The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.DVDRip.x264.AC3')
word.append('Guzoo.1986.VHSDVDRiP.x264.AC3.HS.ES-SHAG')
```

I want to remove the words starting from VHSDVDRIP and DVDRIP onward. So from The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.DVDRip.x264.AC3 to The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995. and Guzoo.1986.VHSDVDRiP.x264.AC3.HS.ES-SHAG to Guzoo.1986.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
re.findall(r"\b\." + 'DVDRIP' + r"\b\.", word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.split` for that ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/peYeqs/1)):

```
s = 'The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.DVDRip.x264.AC3'

import re

print( re.split(r'(\.[^.]*dvdrip\.)', s, 1, flags=re.I)[0] )
```

Prints:

```
The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995
```

Some test cases:

```
lst = ['The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.DVDRip.x264.AC3',
       'Guzoo.1986.VHSDVDRiP.x264.AC3.HS.ES-SHAG']

import re

for item in lst:
    print( re.split(r'(\.[^.]*dvdrip\.)', item, 1, flags=re.I)[0] )
```

Prints:

```
The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995
Guzoo.1986
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to replace those instances, that I'm guessing, with an empty string, maybe this expression with an `i` flag may be working:

```
import re

regex = r"(?i)(.*)(?:\w+)?dvdrip\W(.*)"

test_str = """
The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.DVDRip.x264.AC3
Guzoo.1986.VHSDVDRiP.x264.AC3.HS.ES-SHAG
"""

subst = "\\1\\2"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.x264.AC3
Guzoo.1986.VHSx264.AC3.HS.ES-SHAG
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BJBlil/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/BJBlil/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Consider re.sub:

```
import re
films = ["The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.DVDRip.x264.AC3", "Guzoo.1986.VHSDVDRiP.x264.AC3.HS.ES-SHAG"]

for film in films:
    print(re.sub(r'(.*)VHSDVDRiP.*|DVDRip.*', r'\1', film))
```

Output:

```
The.Eternal.Evil.of.Asia.1995.
Guzoo.1986.
```

Note: this leaves the trailing period, as requested.